# Interpresting R^2 and F-test of data with different variances

Tags: regression, f-test

I have results where the sum of squared errors are very similar (SSE=Sum(y_Est-y)^2) but the corresponding R^2 are very different as are the F-test results.

The coefficient of determination can be defined as R^2 = 1 - SSE/SST which can be interpreted as 1-(unexplained variation)/(total variation).

Now I have a situation in which the SSE's are very similar, but the SST are very different. The net result is one regression has an R^2 of over 0.6 and the other has 0.05!

It's having a similar effect on the F-test: SSM/SSE. For similar reasons the SSM for the less volatile regression is much lower and so it has a much lower F-score.

It seems strange to me that although both regressions give a fit of similar quality the second one gets penalised simply because it is applied to less volatile data?

Clearly the disparity in volatility between the two time series is skewing the results. In such a situation how should I compare the regression results between data that has different levels of volatility.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SSE and SST are not really very interpretable by themselves.  You can increase or decrease them, for instance, by changing the scale.  That's one reason for using F tests and R squared and so on.

The volatility of a time series should absolutely affect the results. That's not "skewing" and it's not odd.

Comment: Understood still seems a bit strange in my situation. I am trying to fit the same type of data on both days, to in terms of SSE you are comparing like with like. Yet the second one gets penalised simply because its modelling the less volatile data. Are there any other statistical tests I can use that are less sensitive to the relative volatility of the two data sets?

Comment: I am not a specialist in time series, but I would doubt it.  It seems counter to basic statistical practice. Volatility is key.